# Predictive text search box

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a predictive search box that performs almost exactly as the example provided by codpen below.

How would I edit the code so that instead of predicting just the word 'California', I could have an array of strings that it predicts for?

Additionally is it possible to make it so that once a word is complete, the script attempts to predict the next word being typed?

https://codepen.io/sivarp18/pen/ewbmx

```js
$("#search").keyup(function(){
  $("#background-input").val('');
  var city = "california";
  var searchText = $("#search").val();
  console.log(searchText.toLowerCase());
  if(searchText === "")
    $("#background-input").val('');
  else if(city.indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase())==0)
    {
      var currentLength = searchText.length;
      $("#background-input").val(searchText+""+city.substring(currentLength));     
    }
});
```

```css
#search-div
{
  position: relative;
}
#background-input
{
  position: absolute;
  color: #999999;
  height:25px;
  width:250px;
}
#search
{
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
  height:25px;
  width:250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="search-div">
  <input type="text" id="background-input" />
  <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type california.." />
</div>
```

Comment: I would imagine you'd have to loop over your array of strings every time a character is entered and determine if the characters entered in the input (partially) matches any of the strings.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to implement a loop in your existing code after your else/if statement to loop through each of your cities in the array, and execute the following code on each of the strings in the array.

This code works for me -

```
$("#search").keyup(function(){
  $("#background-input").val('');
  var cities = ["california", "london", "paris"];
  var searchText = $("#search").val();
  console.log(searchText.toLowerCase());

  if(searchText === "")
    $("#background-input").val('');
  else {
      for(var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++){
        if(cities[i].indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase())==0)
            {
            var currentLength = searchText.length;
            $("#background-input").val(searchText+""+cities[i].substring(currentLength));     
        }
    }
  }
});
```